# Reputation icon should change when there is activity in Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I was wondering why the reputation icon in Stack Exchange app (Android) doesn't change when there is a reputation change, so it is hard to know when there a rep change, given the icon is always white, and we only can know, if you tap the icon.

I think would be good if the icon could change (same as the comment change when we receive comments), for something like we have in the site or at least just turning to the color green (like when we are awarded with badges on desktop).

Comment: You're not made aware of any changes to your reputation unless you explicitly interact with the feed anyway, so I'm not sure what value this would bring; those that were interested in looking at their reputation while in the mobile app would already be on the view that gives them the most up-to-date information.

Comment: not always the reputation in feed are up-to-date, so could be one reason

Comment: That's my point; you have to refresh the feed to get any status updates for the day *anyway*.  Reputation isn't sent along to the mobile app in the same way notifications are.

Comment: Exactly, so instead of refreshing, why not just get instant notifications, and keep them if you don't tap them? just like the desktop... Refreshing ,at least for me, not always work, sometimes give me past reputation (day before) or something similar.

Comment: Because of that missing feature, I use the browser instead of the app. Seeing the green reputation marker is important, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Nice catch, but then again... if it should refresh automatically, imagine a troll up/downvoting all your posts because reasons. If you are on mobile internet, then it can be data-annoying.

Also, it can be annoying anyway, because you get a notification when there is a reply or a comment, but if there were even rep notifications, then you'd get confused when it'd e.g. vibrate only because you got -2 to 15(+ badge awards) points per notification, which if you are a low user seems irrelevant, however if you are one of those users who have a "farm" for reputation, you'd uninstall the app pretty fast just to avoid it.

Comment: You misunderstood my point. I didn't meant for receiving notifications in mobile neither vibrate nor lead activity, but only inside the APP just for the icon changes when there is activity, which wouldn't be that data-annoying.

Comment: The icon would change if something comes up i.e. you need to _check_ in intervals first if there is something new and then change the icon. If there was check for each new rep, then I see an issue. The notifications can be avoided, but you won't avoid refreshing, which may be data-consuming if you catch a troll or you have a farm. I think this is even the reason why it's not implemented as continuous checking for rep, because even farmers use the app and not everyone has unlimited data on mobile network. However I can see it working if a check would perform only on comment/answer notification